# ssis expression: how do you trim a value then check if the vale is empty then add a null value?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My current expression any help would be great thank you!

```
TRIM(Unit) == "N/A" ? (DT_STR,255,1252)NULL(DT_STR,255,1252) : 
TRIM(Unit) == "" ? (DT_STR,255,1252)NULL(DT_STR,255,1252) :  [Unit]
```

it will add null to empty values however how do i trim it?

For exmaple if the value is empty then it will add a null, but if the value is space HGDS it will not trim it.

The solution as below

```
 TRIM(Unit) == "N/A" ? (DT_STR,255,1252)NULL(DT_STR,255,1252) : 
 TRIM(Unit) == "" ? (DT_STR,255,1252)NULL(DT_STR,255,1252) :  TRIM([Unit])
```

Comment: Please post your solution - just to help other folks with a similar issue.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: TRIM(Unit) == "N/A" ? (DT_STR,255,1252)NULL(DT_STR,255,1252) : TRIM(Unit) == "" ? (DT_STR,255,1252)NULL(DT_STR,255,1252) : TRIM([Unit])

Comment: If you solved it, add your solution as an answer, which you will be able to accept in a couple of days

Comment: @neo Post it below as a proper answer. As noted, you can accept your own answer after a few days. It will help future readers as well as OCD people like me who see 0 answer SSIS questions and have to click on them.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-posting the answer by @Neo in the comments... So that people don't overlook the question thinking that it was unanswered.

TRIM(Unit) == "N/A" ? (DT_STR,255,1252)NULL(DT_STR,255,1252) : TRIM(Unit) == "" ? (DT_STR,255,1252)NULL(DT_STR,255,1252) : TRIM([Unit])

NOTE : @Neo : Feel free to delete my answer and Re-post your answer when ever you see this.